# Display View counts of Questions in Mobile version

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I often use Stack Exchange sites from my smartphone. It works great, but I always have to switch to full version to see view counts of a question. Can you please add it?
There's plenty of space on question page for it to place. I request community to suggest a location.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree there is plenty of space for it. Looking at this question now on my mobile, and I dunno... I'd hate for it to displace the vote interface at all.

Comment: @AndrewBarber What about space present at left side of user (asker) box..

Comment: It could fit there, sure; it might seem out of place since that's user info, not post info. **Then again...** when edits are done, that's where they show up. Hmm... It's just there's already such a small amount of space! agh!

Comment: My screen size is 4-inch, so I always encounter space below tags (right side of star). For smaller screen, there must be space below star icon.. Dynamic adjustment will be great..

Comment: No space is below the star for me. mOst titles are two lines on my screen, but even a three line title would only push the tags down to about equal with the star.

Comment: anyway... **my** screen isn't the only important one here, so I don't want to take over this. hehe... if they added it whereever, I would enjoy seeing the extra info. :)

Comment: Sad to see this is such an old post, without a concrete answer.  There's plenty of room in the mobile site layout, as well as the phone app, to show post views. You don't have to update the counter real-time, just on refresh or lazy-load.