# Number of question views on mobile version

Tags: support, mobile-web

Is there a specific reason that the number of views is not included as a feature on the mobile version?

I understand there are certain features which are better to be viewed on desktop rather than on a mobile device.

However, the number of views for a question, which is shown along with the topic title on left on the desktop browser shouldn't be much resource consuming to be displayed on the mobile browsers too.

Is it specific to the desktop/mobile browser or is it a feature which is not at all included for mobile browsers.

I am only talking about mobile version and not the mobile application.

Comment: @Braiam, thanks for the edit. I thought it is a feature request.

Comment: "Why is this so?" is a [tag:support] request; "I don't think this should be so, please change it." is a [tag:feature-request]. Your question appears to be *phrased* as a support request, but with a feature request hiding between the lines. Generally, we prefer a more direct approach here; if you really meant this as a feature request, it would be better to rephrase it to actually ask for the feature to be implemented.

Comment: Also note that, if you do rewrite your question as a feature request, some people may vote it down if they disagree with the feature you're requesting. This is perfectly normal here on Meta, and should not be taken as personal criticism.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, Thanks for the comment. Well, I am not sure if it is a feature request or not. However, I just want to know whether this feature is actually only applicable to desktop browsers. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, looks like [someone else already requested this feature.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121974/display-view-counts-of-questions-in-mobile-version) Since you're not sure if your post is supposed to be a feature request or not, I'm not sure if it's a duplicate or not. ;) But I'm kind of inclined to think that it is.